# How many times does this statement in a triply-nested loop execute?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, time-complexity

This is my problem

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        for(k=1;k<=j;k++)
            x++;
```

Now, I want to know the statement x++; how many iterate??
I want to know the formula of solution.

Comment: Figure out the 2D case first.

Comment: It's the volume of a simplex, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the value of the following summation:

```
  Sum(i from 1 to n)
      Sum (j from 1 to i)
          Sum (k from 1 to j)
              1
```

Working from the inside out:

```
  Sum(i from 1 to n)
      Sum (j from 1 to i)
          Sum (k from 1 to j)
              1
= Sum(i from 1 to n)
      Sum (j from 1 to i)
          j

= Sum(i from 1 to n)
      i(i + 1) / 2
```

From here, we get

> sum (i from 1 to n) i(i + 1) / 2
>
> = (1/2) sum (i from 1 to n) (i<sup>2</sup> + i)
>
> = (1/2) (sum (i from 1 to n)i<sup>2</sup> + sum (i from 1 to n) i)
>
> = (1/2) (n(n + 1)(2n + 1) / 6 + n(n + 1) / 2)

You can then try to simplify that polynomial to get a clean, exact value.  If you just need the asymptotic upper bound, it's Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20%281/2%29%20%28n%28n%20%2b%201%29%282n%20%2b%201%29%20/%206%20%2b%20n%28n%20%2b%201%29%20/%202%29), this is

> n<sup>3</sup> / 6 + n<sup>2</sup> / 2 + n / 3

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for getting the same answer as I did ! :)
Maybe you should add a more closed form : n(n+1)(2n+4)/12.